# Return Custom Errors to ajax post error function from JsonResult Method and display it under Validation Summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, post, jsonresult, validationsummary

I have Action Method of types "JsonResult". I call it using ajax post. I want to return the custom errors from the action method back to ajax post and display those errors  as validation Summary.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegisterUser(RegistrationModel model)
{
   //if username already exists return custom error to be displayed on view      
   //under validation summary
   // control should go back to error function with message to be displayed.
}


   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            success(result)
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            error(req, status, error);
        }
    });

  function success(result) {  
    //Do Something
  }

  function error(req, status, error) {
       //Display error messages under validation summary.
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, when you do an ajax post, it doesn't care if the Model Validation passed or not, it only cares if it got a response from the server. If an Exception gets thrown from the server, then it will hit your ajax error function.

So what I would do is return a json object that lets me know the validation status.

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid){
        var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
        var message = "Please fix the following: " + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (var modelStateError in modelStateErrors)
        {
            message += modelStateError.ErrorMessage + Environment.NewLine;
        }

     return Json(new {success = false, response = message})
}


 // Do other logic

return Json(new {success = true, response = "Successful message"})
```

Once you pass this object back, you can do the following Javascript

```
success: function (result) {
            if(result.success === true){
                 $('#status-div').empty().html('<div class="success">' + result.response + '</div>');
            }
            if(result.success === false){
                 $('#status-div').empty().html('<div class="fail">' + result.response + '</div>');
            }

        }
```